# Passing a parameter in a Joomla! module

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

I am creating a simple module in joomla. I have a file mod_progress.php.

```
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );
// Include the syndicate functions only once
require_once( dirname(__FILE__).'/helper.php' );
require( JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath( 'mod_progress' ) );

$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addStyleSheet(JURI::base() . 'modules/mod_progress/tmpl/styles.css');

$percentValues = htmlspecialchars($params->get('percentValues'));
```

The last line is what of interest here. I want to take the variable $percentValues and pass it on for use in the module's default.php template.

In my default.php all I have is:

```
<?php echo $percentValues; ?>
```

This does not work. The error I get tells me the variable is undefined.

However, if I do:

```
<?php $percentValues = htmlspecialchars($params->get('percentValues'));
 echo $percentValues; ?>
```

It works just fine.  Can someone explain why I can't use the variable?There must be something big I am missing. Using Joomla! 3.1.

Thank you in advance.

Jared

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rearrange your code

```
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );
// Include the syndicate functions only once
require_once( dirname(__FILE__).'/helper.php' );

$percentValues = htmlspecialchars($params->get('percentValues'));

$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addStyleSheet(JURI::base() . 'modules/mod_progress/tmpl/styles.css');

require( JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath( 'mod_progress' ) );
```

Should declare the variable before include the layout.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know why it cares about the order? Just curious.